# Is it possible to stop nginx from responding when Node.js API goes down?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm just wondering if it's possible to somehow stop nginx from responding to requests, when my Node API goes down? And when the API comes back up, start responding to requests again.

I would like to do this because it would fix issues with my uptime monitor. When the API goes down, nginx continues to return code `502` to every request, and my uptime monitor sees this as a response and does not show that the API is down.

Comment: Fix the uptime monitor instead. If it's worth its salt, it should consider all HTTP status codes >= 400 as "not up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smarter way would in my opinion be to adjust the uptime monitor to interpret every 5xx as an error and therefore no uptime as per HTTP standard [5xx Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) are always errors.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I have set up now, but it still returns response times, even when the API is down. But it really doesn't matter too much, so I'll mark this as the best answer.

Comment: Maybe see it as an extra metric on how your NGINX is responding ;)